# is there a method to filter into dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i have a dataframe like :

```
id      ;   dic
AZE21   ; {"Sport20" : 3 , "Football12":5, "Handball43":19,"Tennis98":32}
BA433   ; {"voiture23": 5 , "BMW32" : 19 , "Vélo81":10}
PA234   ; {"TV98": 12 , "Ordinateur83": 19 }
```

and i have a list  like  ["Sport","TV","Tennis"] . so i want to delete term in this list from each line of "dic".
for example for this line :

```
AZE21   ; {"Sport20" : 3 , "Football12":5, "Handball43":19,"Tennis98":32}
```

we want to delete "Sport20" , "Tennis98" because "Sport" and "Tennis" in the list ....

i want to have an output like :

```
id      ;   dic
AZE21   ; { "Football12":5, "Handball43":19}
BA433   ; {"voiture23": 5 , "BMW32" : 19 , "Vélo81":10}
PA234   ; { "Ordinateur83": 19 }
```

the bit of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lst1 = ["AZE21","BA433","PA234"]
lst2 = [{"Sport20" : 3 , "Football12":5, "Handball43":19,"Tennis98":32},{"voiture23": 5 , "BMW32" : 19 , "Vélo81":10},{"TV98": 12 , "Ordinateur83": 19 } ]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst1,lst2)), columns = ['id','dic'])
```

Comment: From the tags, you are using pandas. Can you paste a pandas representation of this dataframe?

Comment: thank you i ve edited the post

Comment: @jakub i edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) together with a custom function as follows:

```
lst_target = ["Sport","TV","Tennis"]    

def match_partial_key(dic):
    dic_keys = list(dic.keys())
    for key in dic_keys:
        for l in lst_target:
            if key.startswith(l):
                dic.pop(key)
    return dic

df['dic'] = df['dic'].map(match_partial_key)





print(df)

      id                                          dic
0  AZE21          {'Football12': 5, 'Handball43': 19}
1  BA433  {'voiture23': 5, 'BMW32': 19, 'Vélo81': 10}
2  PA234                         {'Ordinateur83': 19}
```